# Finding all classes/modules loaded through require/include

Tags: ruby

Is there a way in Ruby to find all classes/modules load through require/include in the current script?

Answer (score 0):

Not retroactively. AFAIK the runtime doesn't keep any record of where something was loaded from, so there's no way to tell if the current script was the one that loaded the file responsible for the creation of a particular class or module. The closest you can get is to either keep track of what you're loading yourself or walk ObjectSpace to find all the classes and modules that are loaded at a given point in time.

Answer (score 0):

Classes and Modules are constants.

So if you were to grab all the constants from Object, and then do a require, and subtract that information from your call after the load, you would see anything that is new.

It might look something like this:

```
my_constants = Object.constants
require 'my_library'
new_classes_and_modules = my_constants - Object.constants
```